# datastore does not show false boolean

Tags: java, google-app-engine, boolean, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore "table" with multiple fields. One of the fields is a boolean called `banned`. I use it to ban users. Per my design, the field is never to be set except by a human moderator. But the thing is because no instance of the field is True, it is not present in the datastore. So I try to force the field to who by expressly setting it to false when a user creates an account. But of course that made no difference. So my question is this: **How do I get app-engine datastore to show my boolean field even if it is false?** Note that I just added the field to an existing database. And of course i am creating a new account just to see if the field would show up as `false` for the new account and the usual `<missing>` for the existing accounts. But nothing.

Answer (score 2):

*"because no instance of the field is True, it is not present in the datastore..."*

If you set a property, the entity will have it. It does not matter if other entities have the same property or not. If you set a property and do not see it, there is an error somewhere.

*"So I try to force the field... by expressly setting it to false..."*

There is no need to do that. If "false" is a default setting, you don't need to store it. For example (using Datastore API):

```
if (user.isBanned()) {
    entity.setProperty("banned", true);
}

Boolean banned = (Boolean) entity.getProperty("banned");
user.setBanned(banned != null && banned);
```

This is especially useful if "banned" is an indexed property. Since, hopefully, the vast majority of your users are not banned, it will save you space as "banned" property - and an index for it - will be created only for banned users.

Comment: The real problem of course, if you haven't inferred, is that without a field, I cannot go and manually turn it to `True`. So I need the field to exist. Also, actually, if the field were to have at least one instance of `True`, then all new instances will actually show up as `False`. So really it's just not there because there hasn't been any `true`.

Comment: So are you saying that my problem is dataNucleus and that if I use the datastore api it will work? I am not clear on what you are saying just yet. Please clarify for me. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, I would recommend to never do anything manually in the Datastore viewer unless it's an emergency - you can easily corrupt your data. Create a simple handler to ban users, if you don't have a proper Admin app (or, at least, a page) for user management. Second, "if the field were to have at least one instance of True, then all new instances will actually show up as False" - this is not how the Datastore works. There is something in your code that sets (or doesn't) this property to "false" or "true".

Answer (score 0):

Actually explicitly setting the boolean value to `false` is the correct approach. Therefore my guess is that the place where you are setting it to false is not executing. Maybe it's inside an if or other conditional that is not reached. So look into that.

A side note for Java developers. Normally it is not necessary to set a boolean to false since that is the default. But in this case you have to either set it or initialize it to false.

Comment: This is not the Java issue, it's the Datastore issue. And there is no need to set a property to a datastore entity unless you actually use it. And in this case, the absence of a property is as good as the property set to "false".